# LinqToXML proper null checking with multiple child layers

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Let's say I am expecting XML as follows and I'm trying to pull the data in layer3:

```
<Layer1>
   <Layer2>
      <Layer3>Test</Layer3>
   </Layer2>
</Layer1>
```

C#:

```
var data = doc.Element("Layer1").Element("Layer2").Element("Layer3");
```

If the layer1 or layer2 elements are missing this will result in a null exception.  I'm been wrapping these queries with try/catch and defaulting the variable in the catch block but this method smells.  Is there a better way to set the "data" variable to null if any of the layers are missing?

Comment: Will you know the keyname for layer3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var data = doc.Elements("Layer1").Elements("Layer2").Elements("Layer3").SingleOrDefault();
```

Note the use of **Element*s***.

[`IEnumerable<T : XContainer>.Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351784.aspx) returns a *collection* of the child elements. The collection might be empty, but it won't be null. Thus, you can chain `Elements` calls without fear of a `NullReferenceException`.

---

As a side note, this is what VB does when you write

```
Dim data = doc.<Layer1>.<Layer2>.<Layer3>.SingleOrDefault()
```

(although in VB, you'd use the handy [`IEnumerable<XElements>.Value` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384768.aspx) instead of SingleOrDefault, which is, unfortunatley, unavailable in C#. Please leave a comment if you know of a C# equivalent.)